# Data is not being inserted, query execute doesn't seem to run

Tags: php, mysql

I have a function that collects data and puts it into an object. It then converts this object into a json string, and places it into a table. It takes about 30 seconds to do it.

Now, this json string is fairly big (roughly 36mb or so).

But when I execute the query, nothing gets put into the table, and I don't get any errors.

So I did some debugging, and the code now looks like this:

```
function __construct($total, $allActions, $employees, $branches, $companies, $departments, $lastUpdated, $update = false)
    {
        echo "Made it to constructor. Update: ".json_encode($update);
        global $conn;
        $this->Total = $total;
        $this->AllActions = $allActions;
        $this->Employees = $employees;
        $this->Branches = $branches;
        $this->Companies = $companies;
        $this->Departments = $departments;
        $this->LastUpdated = $lastUpdated;
        if($update) {
            try {
                $query = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO actionplansummarydata_new (json, last_updated) VALUES (?, ?)");
                echo "Prepared query.";
                if($query->bind_param('ss', json_encode($this), $this->LastUpdated->format("Y-m-d H:i:s"))) {
                    echo "Bound parameters.";
                    if ($query->execute()) {
                        echo "Executed query.";
                    } else {
                        echo "Error inserting summary: " . $query->error;
                    }
                } else {
                    echo "Error binding query: " . $query->error;
                }
            } catch(Exception $ex) {
                echo "Exception: ".$ex->getMessage();
            }
        }
    }
```

Now, when this is executed, this is the response I get on the page:

> Made it to constructor. Update: truePrepared query.Bound parameters.

But I have an if statement here:

```
            if ($query->execute()) {
                echo "Executed query.";
            } else {
                echo "Error inserting summary: " . $query->error;
            }
```

**Neither** of these gets echoed to the page, nor do I get any exceptions.

I'm completely baffled.

The server is MariaDB 10.4, the `json` field in the database is `longtext`, so it should be able to store it.

Comment: this may be helpful in debugging the query
https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.debugdumpparams.php

Comment: @SeifHatem How would that help? That last line which prints the debugging will never get reached.

Comment: please post the result of json_encode($this)

Comment: @nbk I would rather not, as it contains employee information.

Comment: json is only text so sanitize the content in an editor.

Answer (score 3):

If your error reporting is at E_ALL, you should not be facing a silent fail with the query execution... In any case, first of all, some steps in troubleshooting the point of failure.

Move `json_encode($this)` out of the bind, assign to a variable, and `var_dump` to see what you're actually feeding the binder. So too with `$this->LastUpdated->format`; presuming it's a DateTime object, but who knows. Easier to debug when fail-points are outside conditional statements.

Can you confirm whether it works as expected if you insert strings of dummy data instead? E.g.:

```
if($query->bind_param('ss', '{}', '2020-05-19 01:01:01')); {
```

One problem here is with the fact that [bind_param](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) binds variables by reference, not by value. Therefore, you can't feed it with functions. You have to assign the values to variables and only then bind them (because a function doesn't return a usable reference). Meaning, change to:

```
$json = json_encode($this);
$updated = $this->LastUpdated->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
if($query->bind_param('ss', $json, $updated)) {
```

You can assign the bind result (true/false) into a variable, then `var_dump`. (We'd rather not `var_dump` from inside the conditional statement, right?) The bind would fail === false for reasons above. Likewise, `var_dump` the prepared query to ensure it succeeds, tracing each step.

A fatal error might be triggered by the database engine acting up, quite possible with the size of your insert query. You may want to look up MariaDB error logs for more clues, in case you're hitting a limit somewhere. I'd guess with [max_allowed_packet](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/packet-too-large.html), default 16MB, you're well over it. (Also see [mysqli_stmt::send_long_data](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.send-long-data.php) for sending long data in blocks.)

In other issues, `json` is a reserved word in MySQL 8.0 (not listed as such for Maria 10.4?!). You may want to rename the column to ensure it doesn't become a problem (even if it works here).

As far as how this scenario is possible, what you describe (no output from the if/else) only makes sense if there's a fatal error triggered by the `$query->execute()` that's never displayed. Unless there's a bug in PHP error reporting with certain MySQL failures. Do triple-check your PHP error reporting configuration, including anywhere in your code/.htaccess that might override php.ini.

Comment: The query works if the json string is small enough. Also, `bind_param binds variables by reference`. This doesn't seem to be true, as I said, it works fine **if** the string is small enough to be inserted. I've set the `max_allowed_packet` to 400mb and I'm still facing the same issue. My error config seems okay, because all other fatal errors are shown.

Comment: What do you get if you `var_dump` the bind statement? Have you looked at your MySQL error logs?

Answer (score 1):

Check the setting of `max_allowed_packet`; this may be stopping you.  Set it to 1G.

If that does not work, there may be timeout issues, or some other size limitation.

For large text strings, I sometimes like to compress them, and stored the string into a `MEDIUMBLOB`.

Answer (score 0):

what data type that you are using to store the 36MB of JSON string ? you probably need to change the data type to LONGTEXT that can store up to 4GB of data or JSON data type that can store up to 1GB of data

or

you can store it individually as columns in a table and change it back to JSON on your code when needed

Answer (score -1):

Try to check if prepared

```
 if($query = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO actionplansummarydata_new (json, last_updated) VALUES (?, ?)")){
        $query->bind_param('ss', json_encode($this), $this->LastUpdated->format("Y-m-d H:i:s"));
        if($query->execute()){
            // code here
        }

}
```

Comment: If it didn't prepare, why would it allow me to bind? Usually this stuff throws errors.

Comment: you always should check if prepared and then bind the parameters

Comment: And if it didn't prepare, it would throw an error when trying to bind. Something like "cannot call bind on non-object".

Comment: also json_encode() function returns json encoded data and not string so you can't bind json directly, try to save it into variable before inserting like $str = json_encode(data); and then bind it

Comment: Never had issues with that before either, it's something to do with the size of the string going in.